# removing document from collection during find

Tags: mongodb

how do I delete a document during iteration (using a cursor)?

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
    print( "user: " + myDoc.name );
    // now I'm done with it
    myDoc.remove(); // <-- this doesn't work
} );
```

is there a way to do it without having to do a separate search?

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
    print( "user: " + myDoc.name );
    // now I'm done with it
    db.users.findOneAndDelete(myDoc); // <-- this does work
} );
```

while the later does work, it seems like doing a search after already having the document would significantly slow down the process. (Am I wrong?)

Comment: This is not a good idea because you will need to do `db.collection.deleteOne(myDoc)` for each document. I suggest you retrieve the `_id` of all those documents want to delete and use `db.collection.deleteMany()` when you are done.

Comment: my concern is lack of atomicity, I'm building with the requirement that at any time the machine will turn off. I'm concerned that at any time I do processing on many documents and not delete 'till after all are done updating, I will end up with many duplicates. Duplicating a single document once in a while is within reasonable margin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can first search objects and keep **_id**s in an array. And then use following code to remove all the elements once.

```
db.users.deleteMany(
      { "_id": {$in:idArray} },
      function(err, results) {

      }
   );
```

**EDIT**

I found a bulk approach to do that.

```
var bulk = db.users.initializeUnorderedBulkOp();
bulk.find( { "_id": {$in:idArray} }).remove();
bulk.execute();
```

according to my experiance, you can reduce the execution time more than 10 time faster if you use bulk operations since it reduces IO operations.

Comment: This is the better approach than what the OP is taken, but just to correct your terminology this is **not** a Bulk Operations action explicitly speaking. `.deleteMany()` just wraps the `.remove()` call to make a distinction between inclusion or exclusion of the `"justOne"` option, so just like `.update()` there is a choice on whether this affects "all" matched documents or not, but it's not "really"  what is called a "bulk" operation. Technically though, "all" MongoDB write operations API functions actually use the Bulk API underneath now. Even if they only affect one document.

Comment: @NeilLunn, Thank you sir, And are there any Bulk approach to delete from Mongodb?

Comment: Well there is, if you read ["Bulk"](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/). But there would be little need for that unless it really was not practical to provide a list via `$in`. But since both  would essentially involve sending large arrays ( either of _id values or operations ) to the server, then it's kind of a moot point.

Comment: To be "truly Bulk" you would instead just be iterating the array and doing `bulk.find({ "_id": id }).remove()` for every individual item. Then calling `.execute()` on the built up batch. Just calling with `$in` is exactly what I said the underlying driver methods are actually doing underneath a `.removeMany()` anyway. It's "Po<tay>to" "Po<tah>to" really. Same end result.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findAndModify`. Read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.findAndModify/)

```
db.collection.findAndModify({
    query: <document>,
    remove: <boolean>
});
```

This function will return the deleted document, which you can use to print. You can loop it until no more documents are left.

**EDIT**:

Another approach you can take is using `find` and `bulkWrite(deleteMany)`.
First find and print all the docs. Then delete them using a bulkWrite operation.

```
db.users.find().forEach(function(myDoc) {
    print( "user: " + myDoc.name );
});

//This is much faster than your current approach of 
//finding and deleting singe documents

db.users.bulkWrite([
    {
        removeMany: <query>
    }
]);
```

[bulkWrite() - MongoDB](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.bulkWrite/#bulkwrite-write-operations-deleteonemany)

Comment: that looks good, but unfortunately only does one document at a time, instead of returning a cursor.

Comment: @Daniel So, what is the problem in that?

Comment: I (perhaps wrongly) assume that there is a performance penalty compared to batch operations. I didn't realize that `bulkWrite` had the ability to remove. I will give this a try, looks promising.